# Allow User to Extract Data Dumps From DW

Tags: data-warehouse, azure-synapse

We use synapse in azure as our warehouse and create reports in power bi for our users on top of this. We currently have a request to move all of the data dumps from our production system onto our warehouse DB as some of them are causing performance issue in production when run. We've been looking to re-do these into reports in power bi, however in some instances we still need to provide the "raw" data in csv/excel format. This has thrown an issue as some of these extracts are above 150k rows and therefore we can't use power bi to provide the extract as it has a limit on the rows it can export. Our solution would be to build a process to runs against the db and spits out a file into sharepoint for the user to consume, which we can do however we're unsure of how we could provide a method of the user triggering the extract. One of the ways I was thinking of doing it would be using power apps, however I'm wondering if there is an easier way someone on here might be able to suggest? I just need to provide pages with various buttons that trigger extracts to sharepoint from azure when clicked, which can be controlled by security in some way. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Paginated Report Export doesn't have that row limit.

See, eg
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-automate-paginated-integration](https://Export%20Power%20BI%20paginated%20reports%20with%20Power%20Automate)

Or you can use [ADF Copy Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) to create .csv extracts.